# Find differences between two multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, difference

I have two multidimensional arrays that consist of arrays and objects.

```
$new = [
    'a' => 'b',
    'c' => (object)[
        'd' => [1 => 11, 2 => 12],
        'f' => 'Hello',
    ],
];

$old = [
    'a' => 'b',
    'c' => (object) [
        'd' => [1 => 11, 2 => 22],
        'f' => 'Goodbye',
    ],
];
```

I'm trying to find differences between these two arrays by using below function, but the result seems wrong when two objects are compared together. How can I change this function to get correct output?

```
function compare($array1, $array2)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) { 
            if (is_array($value)) { 
            if (array_key_exists($key, $array2)) { 
                    $recursiveArrayDiff = compare($value, $array2[$key]);
                    if (count($recursiveArrayDiff)) {
                        $result[$key] = $recursiveArrayDiff; 
                    }
                    continue;
        }
        else {
            $result[$key] = $value; 
                    continue;
        }
            }
        if (is_object($value)) { 
        if (isset($key, $array2) && is_object($array2[$key])) {
                    $props = array_keys(get_object_vars($value));
                    foreach ($props as $prop) {
                if (isset($array2[$key]->{$prop})) { 
                            if (is_object($value->{$prop}) && is_object($array2[$key]->{$prop})) { 
                                $temp = compare($value->{$prop}, $array2[$key]->{$prop});
                                if (count($temp)) {
                                    $result[$key] = array($prop => $temp); 
                                }
                                    continue;
                                } elseif (is_array($value->{$prop}) && is_array($array2[$key]->{$prop})) { 
                                $temp = compare($value->{$prop}, $array2[$key]->{$prop});
                                if (count($temp)) { 
                                    $result[$key] = array($prop => $temp);
                                }
                                    continue;
                            } else { 
                                if ($value->{$prop} != $array2[$key]->{$prop}) {
                                $result[$key] = array($prop => $value->{$prop}); 
                            }
                            }
                } else {
                $result[$key] = array($prop => $value->{$prop}); 
                }
                        }
                }
        }
            if ($value != $array2[$key]) { 
                $result[$key] = $value; 
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

The correct and wrong outputs are as follows:

```
//correct output
Array
(
    [c] => stdClass Object
        (
            [d] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 12
                )
            [f] => Hello
        )
)
//wrong output
Array
(
    [c] => stdClass Object
        (
            [d] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 11
                    [2] => 12
                )
            [f] => Hello
        )
)
```

Comment: _How can I change this function to get correct output?..._ What output are you expecting?

Comment: Please attach the result you getting as well.. Object comparison can probably be simplified and may not need recursion http://www.zentut.com/php-tutorial/php-compare-objects/